# CIContext memory leak

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-leaks

```
+ (CGImageRef) newFliteredCGImage:(CGImageRef)image withCIFilter:(CIFilter*)filter {
    CIImage* input_image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    NSSize image_size = NSMakeSize(CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                   CGImageGetHeight(image));

    [filter setValue:input_image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    CIImage* output_image = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

    CGColorSpaceRef color_space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmap_context
    = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
                            image_size.width,
                            image_size.height,
                            8,
                            image_size.width * 4,
                            color_space,
                            (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(color_space);

    CIContext* ci_bitmap_context
    = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:bitmap_context
                              options:nil];
    [ci_bitmap_context drawImage:output_image
                          inRect:[output_image extent]
                        fromRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, image_size}];

    CGImageRef result_img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap_context);

    CGContextRelease(bitmap_context);

    return result_img;
}
```

parameter's CGImageRef and return's CGImageRef is released by CGImageRelease but it has memory leak

I think CIContext has a problem but I can't find the problem

please give me help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in @autoReleasePool ..

```
+ (CGImageRef) newFliteredCGImage:(CGImageRef)image withCIFilter:(CIFilter*)filter {

@autoreleasepool {
CIImage* input_image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
NSSize image_size = NSMakeSize(CGImageGetWidth(image),
                               CGImageGetHeight(image));

[filter setValue:input_image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
CIImage* output_image = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

CGColorSpaceRef color_space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmap_context
= CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
                        image_size.width,
                        image_size.height,
                        8,
                        image_size.width * 4,
                        color_space,
                        (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

CIContext* ci_bitmap_context
= [CIContext contextWithCGContext:bitmap_context
                          options:nil];
[ci_bitmap_context drawImage:output_image
                      inRect:[output_image extent]
                    fromRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, image_size}];

CGImageRef result_img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap_context);

return result_img;

}
}
```

hope it helps you ..

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: My pleasure  friend .